# There some bright white or black parts on the edges of result face for seamlessClone

Tags: opencv3.0, opencv3.1, opencv, python

I meet some problem about the function `seamlessClone` of opencv:

Without other op , simply using `seamlessClone` op for blending two face image like `cv2.seamlessClone(src_img, dst_img, src_mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)`, I test 3 cases:

1) When I use  all white mask for `src_mask`, there will be some white bright parts on the some edges of result face. 
2) When I use the same-sized face white mask of src_img for `src_mask`, there will be some bigger white bright parts on the some edges of result face.
3) When I use the eroded face white mask of src_img for `src_mask`, there will be some black parts on the some edges of result face.

I can not find the causes and can not fix it. Can anyone give some advises?

Thanks.
Looking forward to the reply.